# Match sequential values of 2 lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I would like to match sequential value pairs from 2 lists, a and b, and delete values from b list, keep only first larger value for b (compared to a) at same index position as a. lets look at a simple example

```
a = [206, 252, 272, 315, 349, 374, 394, 406, 440, 466]
b = [209, 220, 244, 255, 285, 301, 327, 358, 380, 396, 419, 447, 476, 492]
```

start by looking at value at index 0 in list a
if  b value at index 0 is smaller it shall be removed from b
next look at index 1 in b , if smaller than a[0] it shall also be removed and so on...

final result should be :

```
b = [209,255,285,327,358,380,396,419,447,476]
```

my idea is to try a nested for loop

```
for idx, j in enumerate(a):
    for jdx, k in enumerate(b):
        if b[jdx] < a[idx]:
           del b[jdx]
```

However, I can not get the final result I want...

Comment: Sounds like it could be interesting, but it's very unclear.

Comment: @KellyBundy , tried to clarify. hope it helps

Comment: Still unclear. Would help if you explicitly went through more comparisons/removals (like saying what numbers get compared, what numbers get removed, and how the lists/pointers look after each step).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close, but it doesn't move to the next value in list a like you want. This code gives the intended result:

```
a = [206, 252, 272, 315, 349, 374, 394, 406, 440, 466]
b = [209, 220, 244, 255, 285, 301, 327, 358, 380, 396, 419, 447, 476, 492]
output = []
for idx, j in enumerate(a):
    for jdx, k in enumerate(b):
        if b[jdx] >= a[idx]:
            output.append(b[jdx])
            break
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[209, 255, 285, 327, 358, 380, 396, 419, 447, 476]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an acceptable solution:

```
a = [206, 252, 272, 315, 349, 374, 394, 406, 440, 466]
b = [209, 220, 244, 255, 285, 301, 327, 358, 380, 396, 419, 447, 476, 492]

result = []

try:
    a_iter = iter(a)
    b_iter = iter(b)
    a_value = next(a_iter)
    b_value = next(b_iter)
    while True:

        if a_value < b_value:
            result.append(b_value)
            a_value = next(a_iter)
            b_value = next(b_iter)
        else:
            b_value = next(b_iter)

except StopIteration:
    print(result)
```

Comment: b should not include 492 because after 476 is recorded there are no more values in a for 492 to be compared against. Based on my understanding of his explaination.

Comment: @EliHarold I edited my answer.

Comment: @RobinDillen, thanks nice alternative solution

Comment: @RobinDillen great! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and efficient solution, go to the next index as soon as `b[i]` has become larger than `a[i]`:

```
i = 0
n = len(a)
for b[i] in b:
    if i < n and b[i] > a[i]:
        i += 1
del b[i:]
```

Or with a sentinel:

```
i = 0
a += b[-1:]
for b[i] in b:
    if b[i] > a[i]:
        i += 1
del b[i:]
```